# List closed-source installed applications

Tags: software-installation

Is it possible to list all installed applications/packages that are not open source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program vrms will do this. Run `sudo apt-get install vrms`, and then run `vrms`. This identifies which programs are free/open source by seeing which repository they were installed from. However it will ignore programs you installed by just downloading a .deb file from the web, as they are not from any repository.

Comment: Sounds good, but it's not clear enough for me: `  7 non-free packages, 0.3% of 2061 installed packages. 3 contrib packages, 0.1% of 2061 installed packages.` What does this mean? The other packages are free or not? Also is `free === open source`?

Comment: Free to all intents and purposes == open source. Free actually implies slightly more than open source, but for this it's almost the same thing. So that output tells you that you have 7 completely non open source packages. 3 open source packages that require non open source packages to to be installed and all the other packages are completely open source/free.

Comment: I don't see anything related to `googletalk-plugin`. Does it mean that it's open source?

Comment: Actually I think not, the only way of seeing if a program is open source is to see what repository it is from. googletalk-plugin is from an externally downloaded .deb, so the software doesn't know about it.

Comment: Yeps, but which is the alternative to see all applications (including the ones installed from an externally .dev file)?

Comment: The problem is that it is impossible for the computer to tell if external .debs are open source or not. There is no alternative; this program is a close t what you want as you can get, sorry.

Comment: Update your answer with these details, please.

Comment: I have done as you have asked, hopefully the edit is clear enough.

Comment: I think (virtual) rms would have a bit to say about "free" vs. "open source". ;)

Comment: I said they implied different things, but for this answer it doesn't matter too much. A full explanation would probably require more than a comment :P